# How to run my nw-js app in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, node-webkit, developer-tools

Is there any way to use the browser for development preview?

The reason is because in the browser the Developers tools are attached to the window.

But in the nw.exe it's a separate window and it gets very annoying to switch between them

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think there is a way but, what i always do is split the screen and code.  or you could set the developer tool window to "always on top" so that the developer tool window is never covered by another window.

Comment: How do I set it to be always on top?

Comment: on my ubuntu i'll just right click on the window toolbar and set it to always on top